# What kind of routine maintenance needs to be done for an Apache webserver?

Tags: apache-2.2

I created a Ruby on Rails application for our internal projects and I am using apache as my webserver. It so happens that I became the defacto Administrator for this website. Having no prior experience as a System Admin, I try to learn as things come up.

Question: What sort of routiune maintanance should I be doing for Apache (and if you wish Postgresql, but I might ask the latter as a separate question)?

Comment: Do the Backup thing.

Comment: Very, very broad questions that, while owning merit, isn't well fitted for ServerFault. I suggest reading a book or three on Apache, hanging out on Apache forums (remember, SF isn't a forum), mailings lists and then you'll get to know what kind of routine maintenance you'll need to be doing. Ditto for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it up to date.  Apache is known for security flaws.  And make sure you rotate and delete log files so they don't eat up all your disk space.  Apart from that it's pretty much trouble free.

Comment: It's rarely Apache itself that's the problem, but rather the application code.